# Why this context provider sends null to consumer in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm try to use Context, but every time provider sends null objects to consumer. Please let me know where is wrong in my code. I want to send and state from a component to another. **None of them is the other one's child and both of them under component folder.**

Here comes the process of creating and using and consuming:

ImageContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageContext = React.createContext()
export default ImageContext;
```

in this function the selectedFileName takes the name of selected file
ImageUpload.js

```
onFileChange = event => {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
        this.setState({ selectedFileName: event.target.files[0].name });
    };
```

provider:

```
return (
            <ImageContext.Provider value={{ this.state.selectedFileName }}>
           
                </div>

                    <div onClick={this.onNavToEditor}>

                    {this.listItems()}

                 </div>

            </div>

            </ImageContext.Provider >

        );
```

Consumer:

```js
return (
  <ImageContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => (
     
        <ImageEditor
          includeUI={{
          
            loadImage: {
              path: value.path,
              name: value,
            },
         
    )}
  </ImageContext.Consumer>
);
```

You can see above **path and name** are consuming the context.

**Why provider sends the null object to the consumer?**

I should mention here that I have removed some parts of the code to shorten it.

Comment: I've never used context in react before, but don't you need to place the consumer inside of the provider?

Comment: `Provider` must be on Top level component. I think your `Provider` is not wrapped around `ImageEditor` component

Comment: You don't need to place the consumer in the provider and I haven't seen anything related to place the provider on the top level.